# Maven Plugin API: Get MavenProject from Artifact

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to extract information on all dependencies (recursively) used in my project. It seems like the MavenProject class provides all information that I require. But I can't figure out how to transform an instance of `Artifact` into an instance of `MavenProject`

```
/**
 * 
 *
 * @reqiresDependencyResolution
 *
 */
@Mojo(name = "license-overview", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_SOURCES)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {


    /**
     * @parameter default-value="${project}"
     * @required
     * @readonly
     */
    MavenProject project;


    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {

        Set<Artifact> artifacts= project.getArtifacts();
        for (Artifact artifact : artifacts) {
            //Here I need to access the artifact's name, license, author, etc.
            System.out.println("*** "+artifact.getArtifactId()+"***");
        }

    }
}
```

How to access the information that is located within the pom of my dependency, but is not exported via the `Artifact`s getters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

We can build a project in-memory with the [`ProjectBuilder`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuilder.html) API:

> Builds in-memory descriptions of projects.

By invoking the [`build(projectArtifact, request)`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuilder.html#build%28org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact,%20org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingRequest%29) method with the artifact we're interested in and a [`ProjectBuildingRequest`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuildingRequest.html) (that holds various parameters like location of the remote / local repositories, etc.), this will build a `MavenProject` in-memory.

Consider the following MOJO that will print the name of all the dependencies:

```
@Mojo(name = "foo", requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.RUNTIME)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenProject project;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenSession session;

    @Component
    private ProjectBuilder projectBuilder;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        ProjectBuildingRequest buildingRequest = new DefaultProjectBuildingRequest(session.getProjectBuildingRequest());
        try {
            for (Artifact artifact : project.getArtifacts()) {
                buildingRequest.setProject(null);
                MavenProject mavenProject = projectBuilder.build(artifact, buildingRequest).getProject();
                System.out.println(mavenProject.getName());
            }
        } catch (ProjectBuildingException e) {
            throw new MojoExecutionException("Error while building project", e);
        }
    }

}
```

There are a couple of main ingredients here:

- The [`requiresDependencyResolution`](https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html) tells Maven that we require the dependencies to be resolved before execution. In this case, I specified it to `RUNTIME` so that all compile and runtime dependencies are resolved. You can of course set that to the [`ResolutionScope`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/ResolutionScope.html). you want.
- The project builder is injected with the `@Component` annotation.
- A default building request is build with the parameter of the current Maven session. We just need to override the current project by explicitly setting it to `null`, otherwise nothing will happen.

When you have access to the `MavenProject`, you can then print all the information you want about it, like developers, etc.

If you want to print the dependencies (direct and transitive), you will also need to invoke [`setResolveDependencies(true)`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuildingRequest.html#setResolveDependencies%28boolean%29) on the building request, otherwise, they won't be populated in the built project.