# Getting a Maven project dependency's name

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am writing a Maven plugin and in one Mojo I am reading artifacts of a specific type.

`MavenProject#getDependencyArtifacts` gives me a list of `Artifact`s, which do not have a `name` property.

Is there any way for me to read the `project/name` property from the pom attached to the dependency?

Comment: Yes, you need to build the project in-memory. I answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35459159/1743880

Comment: @Tunaki - great, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Plugin API: Get MavenProject from Artifact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457401/maven-plugin-api-get-mavenproject-from-artifact)