# How do I search through dependencies in a maven plugin to find specific files?

Tags: xml, maven, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I might just be googleing this wrong, so I'm sorry if the answer is stupidly obvious. I am trying to create a Maven plugin which will need to search through every dependency a project has, and find XML files containing a specific namespace.

But I can't figure out how to find all XML files in every dependency of the project? I would prefer getting them as resource streams so that I can parse them directly from the JAR but I'm not picky.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to set the [requiresDependencyResolution](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Mojo.html#requiresDependencyResolution--) on your preferred scope in your Mojo. Next you need to get the [MavenProject](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html#Supported_Annotations), so you can ask its dependencies, which can be both a directory or a jar. From that on you should be able to scan for the xml files.

Comment: Thank you for your help Robert. Could you elaborate a bit on where to get the artifact containing MavenProject? I followed the guide here https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html and found this stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457401/maven-plugin-api-get-mavenproject-from-artifact but i can't quite figure out what to import to access MavenProject.

Comment: After messing around a bit more i am able to get a list of all dependencies in the project represented by org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact. But i can't really find the link between getting the Artifact, and inspecting its contents.

Comment: Now you need to use http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact.html#getFile()

Comment: That was my understanding as well, But there is no handles on Artifact to actually get at what it contains as far as I can see. Are you suggesting that I unpack the Artifact and inspect it through the file system, or am I missing something?

Comment: Right, it is either a jar or a directory (the latter i consider a design flaw, but that is another discussion :) ). So with java.util.jar.JarFile you can read the content per entry, in case of a directory you'll have to scan the directories.